# ASP.NET Boilerplate, test cases with real databases

Tags: c#, integration-testing, aspnetboilerplate

I am using asp.net boilerplate for a project for ASP.NET 5.x. I am trying to create test cases for this project that will call existing test databases (one db for Host and the other db for Tenant). My steps so far were to:

1. In `TestBase` class constructor I am calling a method that will work the same as `MultiTenantMigrateExecuter.Run()` which will Seed the data for the Test Host database and the Test Tenant database (I will be using the host db and a single Tenant db for testing). The seeding will be the same as for the real db, just with different names for the test DBs.
2. Also from the `TestBase` class constructor I am getting the TenantId from the host database.
3. Next I am trying to get any seeded user from the tenant database
   like this: `var user= UsingDbContext(context => context.Users.FirstOrDefault(t => t.UserName== "johndoe"));` but of course this will be calling the HostDb not the TenantDb.

I found a way to make a call to the TenantDb by wrapping the code in a using statement like this, avoidint the `context` and usint the repository, to be able to get the user I need from the TenantDb:

```
using (this.AbpSession.Use(tenant.Id, null))
{
    // get the TenantDb.User here by using the User repository
}
```

... and then like this in every test case I write:

```
using (this.AbpSession.Use(AbpSession.TenantId, AbpSession.UserId))
{
    // make calls to the Tenant database here by using Tenant repository
}
```

but this is not the most clean solution, and it has its limitations.

The question is: Is there a better way in my case, to set in the `TestBase` class the context to make calls to the Tenant database by default instead of the Host database?

I tried this one too, but it doesn't work...

```
protected T UsingTenantDbContext<T>(Func<TestAppDbContext, T> func)
{
    T result;

    using (this.AbpSession.Use(AbpSession.TenantId, AbpSession.UserId))
    {
        using (var context = LocalIocManager.Resolve<TestAppDbContext>())
        {
            context.DisableAllFilters();
            result = func(context);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing a while with the code, I found the answer to my question...
In the TestBase class I've created a new static property:

```
internal static MyAppDbContext tenantContext;
```

Static, because this class will be inherited multiple times, but the tenantContext should be set only once.

Next I've created the following method:

```
protected void CreateTenantDbContext()
{
    if (tenantContext == null)
    {
        using (var context = LocalIocManager.Resolve<MyAppDbContext>())
        {
            // AbpSession.TenantId is set in a previous method.
            // Usin the host context, get the Connection String for the necessary tenant
            var encryptedDbConnString = context.Tenants.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == AbpSession.TenantId)?.ConnectionString;

            // Decrypt the string
            var decryptedDbConnString = SimpleStringCipher.Instance.Decrypt(encryptedDbConnString);

            // Create the context for the tenant db and assign it to the static property tenantContext
            tenantContext = LocalIocManager.Resolve<MyAppDbContext>(new { nameOrConnectionString = decryptedDbConnString });
        }
    }
}
```

Once created you can use it in your test cases.